# Going for PLAB2 exam with my wife and son

Tags: visas, uk, applications, nigerian-citizens

I am a Nigerian doctor working in Saudi Arabia. I have visited the UK twice on a visitor's visa. Now I want to go for PLAB2 in September And I  want to take my wife and my 4 year old son with me. All three of us are in Saudi Arabia. 
What visa should I apply for? Do I need to apply separately for each of us please?

Answer (score 2):

A Standard Visitor visa https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa is the appropriate visa for this scenario. You will need to apply separately for each of you, cross-referencing your family members’ applications to your own as the main applicant.

The PLAB exam is a permitted activity for visitors
https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules

Work-related training

22 Overseas graduates from medical, dental or nursing schools may:

(b) take the following test/examination in the UK:
(i) the Professional and Linguistic Assessment Board (PLAB) test, where the visitor can provide written confirmation of this from the General Medical Council